# Saving data to database in same module or main app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, puppeteer

I wrote a module to scrape a website and extract some info. I want to save this info in database. Is it better to define a save function in module to store data in database or get the info in main app and save it to database?

first implementation:

```
//myModule.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
module.exports = class example {
    async saveToDB() {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('...');
        let x = await page.evaluate(() => {
            ...
            return x;
        });
        await browser.close();
        //save x to DB
    }
}

//app.js
const MyModule = require('./myModule');
let myModule = new MyModule();
setInterval(() => {
    myModule.saveToDB();
}, 10000)
```

second Implementation:

```
//myModule.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
module.exports = class example {
    async getInfo() {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('...');
        let x = await page.evaluate(() => {
            ...
            return x;
        });
        await browser.close();
        return x;
    }
}

//app.js
const MyModule = require('./myModule');
let myModule = new MyModule();
setInterval(() => {
    let x=myModule.getInfo();
    //save x to DB
}, 10000)
```

If you have best propose, let me know, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will be biased.

I like the second version, where I have the scrapping function, database function and the connector/main function separately.

That way, scrapping function has no relation to the database function, but we can still scrape the data and save it to database. It's modular, scalable, nice to read and maintain.

In the first version, saveToDB actually scrapes the page and then does some save, it's misleading. saveToDB should do saveToDB only.

You can learn more about code smell and design patterns below,

- http://elijahmanor.com/javascript-smells/
- https://medium.com/innoarchitech/how-to-write-highly-scalable-and-maintainable-javascript-modules-303597317fdf
- https://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/